# Using "Sequence" in music context

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, academia, music

As a part of my academic paper, I wish to use the "Sequence" word.

Here is the problem:

1. As you can see in the picture, the "Start Time" of each note is mentioned on the time axis. I want to measure the **time differences** between A,B,C, and D but I do not know which terms fit in this context.

- The sequences of notes' start time
- The sequences of starting time of notes
- The sequences of music scores

2. In another part, I trace the time differences when users press the piano keys. Again the same problem

- The sequences of key-pressed events

I would be grateful if you guys could help me to find a suitable term for this context.

[image]

Comment: Is this a paper dealing with the mechanics or electronics of musical instruments or the MIDI protocol rather than a discussion of musical performance? Musicians are used to thinking of sequences of notes but then thinking of the _duration_ of the notes and don't usually think of the notes as being steps on a time scale starting from the sounding of the first note. Also as a point a crotchet is a quater of a semibrieve, not a half of one so the start times should be 0, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75 and 2 rather than as your diagram shows.

Comment: As a musician I'm concerned that the time from the first note (the chord) to the second should not be 1, but 2 for the rest of the timings to be correct. It's also unfortunate that you need to use the word "sequence", which has a specific meaning when discussing music.

Comment: BoldBen's start times would be equally valid.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian We crossed over there. I didn't realise quite what the OP was saying and started on a discussion of note lengths (crotchets, minims and dotted notes) before the penny dropped.

Comment: @BoldBen We did :-) And I did the same as you, but the penny still hasn't dropped here.  I **still** don't know... WAIT! The OP has edited it!

Comment: I generally interpret "sequence" to mean "order", not "timing".  Or a "sequence" is merely an ordered list of some sort.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I edited the figure and remove the time :-), I just added some figures to show the time and unfortunately, I didn't pay attention to the length of the notes.

Comment: @BoldBen, actually I want to collect data from the MIDI file, but I still confused about using the "sequence" word.

Comment: Aren't you simply measuring the durations of the notes, as BoldBen said?

Comment: @HotLicks I think so, do you have any suggestions for this context?

Comment: (Thanks for the edit) Ah! I get it. To find out whether, and by how much, the musician plays the notes early or late. So in MIDI terminology you'll be looking at the 'Note on' times. You have a note-sequence - ie the sheet music or score - the start times of whose notes are easily measured once you know the tempo. If it is crotchet=60 the first chord is on 0", then the next notes are on 4" 5" 6" and 7".... I can't see how the word 'sequence' is going to be useful, except in talking about the note-sequence. (Was your comment meant for me btw?)

Comment: I think your best bet, now that @OldBrixtonian has reminded me of the name of the event, is to talk about a _series_ of Note On events with time offsets from the initial Note On event (however you'd have to pair each one with a Note Off event otherwise it'd sound horrible:-) Of course each Note Off event doesn't have to coincide with the next Note On event because you can play them staccato or sustain them so you allow them to overlap a little. Are you thinking of MIDI files recorded from performance or ones which have been generated electronically?